# Is it irresponsible to use all the available cores and CPU's?

Tags: c++, resources, policy

I'm designing a JPG decoder.  One implementation supports using threads and by extension multiple cores of the CPU.  If the underlying system supports 3 cores my program will use all of them.  Is it irresponsible to use all core resources or are systems designed to mitigate greedy  programs.

Also, the threaded implementation also requires much more memory resources (3 x the size of the equivalent RGB BMP).  When does memory use become too much?

Comment: Let the **user** select how many cores they want to dedicate to a particular task.

Comment: Do you think it is beneficial to start threads etc. etc. to decode a usual JPG file, per file? I´m not. Memory: Code?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I think that would be beyond the knowledge scope of the user.

Comment: @deviantfan I get >25% speed of execution using 3 threads instead of 1.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Most users have no idea about fine tuning. The majority would stick to the defaults, and either complain that it's too slow if you don't use all cores, or complain that it's using too much CPU if you do :-)

Comment: Someone said design is about making choices... and you will be flamed either way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it irresponsible to use all core resources

No, it is not. Consider a single core system: If it were somehow "irresponsible" to use all cores, nothing would ever get done.

> or are systems designed to mitigate greedy programs

Yes, operating systems are specifically designed to do this. In general, two programs of equal priority who each want to use all CPU cores will share the cores 50%-50% (by time, not by core allocation). Each application will believe that it is using all cores, but some cores might appear to run a bit slower than others. The application need not concern itself with this level of detail (although usually the OS provides ways to do so, if required).

Comment: Well put thanks.. I immediately understood.  I guess that explains why sporadically my multithreaded implementation is much slower than my single threaded implementation.